# Adding a section at specific cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented a tableView using PLIST to set properties.

I would like to add three sections at specific row. (row 12, row24, row 35)

I have tried with following code but it will be too much code and not working well.

Images and code are added below.

[image]

```
import UIKit
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

         @IBOutlet var tblStoryList: UITableView!      
          var array = PLIST.shared.mainArray

        var array = PLIST.shared.mainArray
        let sections: [String] = ["First stage","Second Stage","Third Stage"]
        let s1Data : [String] = ["Row1","Row2","Row3"]
        let s2Data : [String] = ["Row4","Row5","Row6"]
        let s3Data : [String] = ["Row7","Row8","Row9"]

        var sectionData: [Int: [String]] = [:]

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            sectionData = [0: s1Data, 1: s2Data, 2: s3Data]
    }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return (sectionData[section]?.count)!
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
            return sections[section]
        }
        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 3
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->

    UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoryTableviewCell", for: indexPath) as! StoryTableviewCell


    //making plist file
    let dict = self.array[indexPath.row]
    let title = dict["title"] as! String
    let imageName = dict["image"] as! String
    let temp = dict["phrases"] as! [String:Any]
    let arr = temp["array"] as! [[String:Any]]
    let detail = "progress \(arr.count)/\(arr.count)"

    //property to plist file
    cell.imgIcon.image = UIImage.init(named: imageName)
    cell.lblTitle.text = title
    cell.lblSubtitle.text = detail

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none


    return cell
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the actual response that you want show in tableView because currently you are setting static data in `sectionData` dictionary and setting data in `cellForRowAt` with your plist array. Also how you know that second section come at row 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexPath.row you are getting in the tableView's cellForRowAt is relative to the section.  You cannot use it directly as the index of your main array (which has all the rows).

You will need to perform a simple calculation to convert the indexPath.row to an index of that array (by offsetting the row with the total item count of previous sections) :

```
let index = [0,12,36][indexPath.section] + indexPath.row
let dict  = array[index]
```

The same thing applies to the response you give to numberOfRowsInSection:

```
return [12,24,35][section]
```

I find it a bit odd that the data structure (PLIST) would be so rigid that it always contains exactly those number of entries and will never change.  I would suggest a more generalized approach if only to avoid spreading hard coded numbers (e.g. 12,24,35,36) all over the place.

for example:

```
  // declare section attributes in your class
  let sectionTitles  = ["First stage","Second Stage","Third Stage"]
  let sectionSizes   = [12,24,35]  // central definition, easier to maintain (or adjust to the data)
  let sectionOffsets = sectionSizes.reduce([0]){$0 + [$0.last!+$1] }

  // and use them to respond to the table view delegate ...

  let index = sectionOffsets[indexPath.section] + indexPath.row
  let dict  = array[index]
  // ...

  return sectionSizes[section] // numberOfRowsInSection
```

Using this approach, you shouldn't need to create sectionData (unless you're using it for other purposes elsewhere).

BTW, in your sample code, the sectionData content is hard coded with data that is not consistent with the expected section sizes so it would not work even with a correct index calculation.

Comment: Thanks I will try to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use switch case in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: